# How to Get xmlHttp.responseText when you call AJAX from IFrame

Tags: php, ajax, iframe

anybody can tell me please how to Get xmlHttp.responseText when you call from IFrame?

I get empty xmlHttp.responseText, while when calling server from out the IFrame, I get the responseText without problem, how can I solve this problem?

Note: I am loading the IFrame content dynamically with the page (source) (IFrameSRC.php), IFrameSRC.php contains the html elements and the button which I click to call the AJAX.

```
<IFrame src="IFrameSRC.php"></IFrame>
```

Inside page IFrameSRC.php:

```
<input type="button" onclick="CallServer()">
```

By the way when I call the server without the IFrame, it works perfect and I am able to get the response text from the AJAX file... Can any body helps me out with this? Thanks.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: just curious, why do you need iframe, if it can be done without it?Iframe is just like another window/tab. Though you can get its html by assigning a identifier..
http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/

Comment: Because I do not need to refresh the whole page... The Src of the IFrame takes more than one PHP page.. It will be heavy to load the whole page each time!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use it in a `div` not an `IFrame` and the `IFrame` is obsoleted of course. You can use libraries like `jQuery` to make your way easy.

http://www.jquery.com

See `.ajax()`;

Comment: OK, I will not need the AJAX, what will I do I will build html elements inside the DIV dynamically by the javascript (document.createElement..)... Thanks a lot for your hint,, Iframes is headache really!

Comment: I'd been using `IFrame` about a year ago, even in important projects but after some recommendations from the experts I changed my mind to use AJAX and a nifty `div`. The `IFrame` has lots of minor and major problems, you really need painkillers when you get to work with them.